# WordPress - How to get IDs for all pages in the current menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

I am building a one page scrolling wordpress theme, and I want to be able to create a simple loop that will basically grab the page id's that are in the current menu, then spit out the content.

I already know how to spit out the content for a page, given the id, but I don't know what the proper way to get all the ids from the current menu is.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
$menuItems = wp_get_nav_menu_items('main-menu');
foreach($menuItems as $page) {
    $post = get_post($page->object_id);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
    echo $content;
}
```